# Unexpected acceptance of user input c++ class

Tags: c++, eclipse, oop

Just started working with classes in C++ and i'm an encountering a strange occurrence when requesting input from the user.

I have two outcomes the conditionals will accept in the `getUserWantToPlay()` member function: 'y' or 'n'.  Otherwise, it will output a message requesting a proper response.  I'm in a very early stage of the build and I was just doing some testing on this member function and I noticed that when I type "yes" or "no" it acts as if I typed 'y' or 'n'.  Why is this happening?

**Application Code**

```
//implementation of TicTacToe
//Using classes this time

#include <iostream>
#include "TicTacToeClass.h"


int main()
{

    //Assumes no play unless user decides they want to play and initializes game variable to TicTacToe class
    bool play = false;
    TicTacToe game;

    play = game.getUserWantToPlay();

    while(play == true)
    {


        std::cout << "Playing the game" << std::endl;
        break;

    }

    return(0);
}
```

**Class Implementation**

```
//TicTacToe class implementation
//Leeroy Jenkins

#include "TicTacToeClass.h"
#include <iostream>


bool TicTacToe::getUserWantToPlay()
{

    char response;
    bool invalidResponse = true;
    bool play = false;

    while(invalidResponse == true)
    {

        std::cout << "Would you like to play a new game of TicTacToe? (y/n) " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> response;

        if(response == 'y')
        {
            invalidResponse = false;

            play = true;
        }
        else if(response == 'n')
        {
            std::cout << "No Problem!";
            invalidResponse = false;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please input a proper response (y/n)" << std::endl;
        }

    }

    return play;
}
```

Comment: _"Why is this happening?"_ because only a single char is read from the input.

Comment: doh.......that's embarrassing.  Thanks!